# How do I access a data nested in JSON in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to figure this out for hours.  I've seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json?noredirect=1&lq=1) and I still cannot figure this out.

I have some Jason data that I know begins like this:

```
{
  "0x123454843eacf5c5318e1234504251b937d12345": [
{
  "poolIndex": 0,
  "stakingStrategy": "masterchef",
  "farmName": "sushiChef",
 ....
```

I've written the following to get at the information like "poolIndex" and "stakingStrategy":

```
  function parseTheDataFunctionSushi(walletAddress, networkName){
  // calls a funciton to pull and parse the api data

    var walletAddress = "0x123454843eacf5c5318e1234504251b937d12345";
    var networkName = "polygon";

    var theparsedJSONdata = pullAndParseAPISushi(walletAddress, networkName)
    console.log("object keys are " + Object.keys(walletAddress)); 
    var firstCrack = theparsedJSONdata[walletAddress][0]['poolIndex']
    console.log("firstCrack is " + firstCrack)
```

This does not work.  I've written `firstCrack` every way I can think of

```
  theparsedJSONdata[walletAddress].poolIndex
  theparsedJSONdata[walletAddress][0].poolIndex
```

None of them work.  So frustrating.  Any help would be appreciated.

For what it's worth, `Object.keys(walletAddress) returns

```
 object keys are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41
```

Here's the other function:

```
  function pullAndParseAPISushi (walletAddress, networkName){

   console.log("walletAddress inside pullAndParseAPISushi is = " + walletAddress);
   console.log("network is " + networkName);
   var apiKEY = "96e0cc51-a62e-42ca-acee-910ea7d2a241";  // API key from Zapper
   var url = "https://api.zapper.fi/v1/staked-balance/masterchef?addresses%5B%5D="+ walletAddress + "&network=" + networkName + "&api_key=" + apiKEY;
   // assembles the API URL with the wallet addressa, network and name
   console.log("url is " + URL);
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // pulls data from the API
   console.log(response)
   var theparsedJSONdata = JSON.parse(response); // parses the JSON response from the API
   console.log(theparsedJSONdata)
   return theparsedJSONdata
 }
```

Comment: Consider undeleting your related question [Do I have to do something to an argument coming from a cell in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67794290/do-i-have-to-do-something-to-an-argument-coming-from-a-cell-in-google-sheets?noredirect=1#comment119830254_67794290) See [Access deleted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366500/13045193).

Comment: This is not reproducible. If the returned JSON and the code are exactly as you mentioned, `theparsedJSONdata[walletAddress][0].poolIndex` should return 0. Can you try logging `theparsedJSONdata` right before calling `theparsedJSONdata[walletAddress][0]['poolIndex']`? What do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data structure is indeed as you specified, then one of the attempts you tried should work. See below for a functional example.

```js
const data = {
  "0x123454843eacf5c5318e1234504251b937d12345": [
    {
      "poolIndex": 0,
      "stakingStrategy": "masterchef",
      "farmName": "sushiChef",
    }
  ]
}

const walletAddress = "0x123454843eacf5c5318e1234504251b937d12345";

console.log(data[walletAddress][0].poolIndex);

console.log(data[walletAddress][0].stakingStrategy);
```

Comment: Thank you!  Stil not working.  I've added this `console.log(theparsedJSONdata[walletAddress][0].stakingStrategy);` and I get the following error:  `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
parseTheDataFunctionSushi`

Comment: is `pullAndParseAPISushi(walletAddress, networkName)` doing an asynchronous action like fetching data?

Comment: I'm in google sheets trying to pull data from Zapper API to track positions in Sushiswap.

Comment: If you `console.log(theparsedJSONdata)` directly, what do you get?

Comment: { '0x123454843eacf5c5318e1234504251b937d12345': 
   [ { poolIndex: 0,
       stakingStrategy: 'masterchef',
       farmName: 'sushiChef',
       rewardAddress: '0x0000000',
       tokenAddress: '0x000000',
       rewardTokenSymbol: 'SUSHI',
       rewardTokenDecimals: 18,
       rewardTokenAddress: '0x000000',
       rewardTokenPrice: 12.12,
       isActive: true,
       label: 'WMATIC / ETH',
       protocol: 'sushiswap',
      ...

Comment: this yields "undefined". `console.log(theparsedJSONdata[walletAddress])`

Comment: Inside `pullAndParseAPISushi`, should this be how the response is parsed? `var theparsedJSONdata = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233211/discussion-between-dbweinstein-and-nick).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
theparsedJSONdata.walletAddress[0].poolIndex
```

don't have enough rep to make a comment but I think this might work, let me know!